# has lain on the ground vs has lain down on the ground

Tags: present-perfect, verb-forms, lie-lay-lain-laid

I want to describe a situation in which a man is in a sleeping position (he is actually not asleep) and will remain in this situation forever (it's a sculpture!). I mean, a sculpture in a sleeping position. How should I describe this? (please see **[this photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bistoon_Kermanshah.jpg)**)

> He has lain on the ground.
>
> He is lying down on the ground.
>
> He has laid down on the ground.

Comment: The first word came to my mind: *reclining*. (You can try searching for images with this keyword: *reclining statue*.)

Comment: I recalled the word *recumbent*. I'm not sure, but "lying" seems to be too horizontal for his position. He is half-sitting, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Present Perfect in your first sentence, but you'd need a duration phrase to make it more natural for this context:

> He has lain on the ground *for centuries*.

Without that duration phrase, the reader might think that "at some period in his life he has lain on the ground, but now he's quite an active guy". This would be unfitting for a statue.

---

In the second sentence, I'd delete **down**:

> He is lying on the ground.

With **down**, it might be understood that he is in the process of lying down: he hasn't yet settled in his position.

---

The third sentence is unfit because **laid** is the past-tense form of **lay**, not of **lie**. "Lay" means to "place something somewhere". It's a transitive verb. That's how we usually use "lay":

> He has laid **the flowers** on the ground.

It's quite hard not to get tangled in the diverse forms of "lay" and "lie". Here's a related question:

- [What is the difference between “lay” and “lie”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-the-difference-between-lay-and-lie)

The ELU StackExchange even has [a special tag to mark questions related to the usage of lay and lie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-lay-lain-laid).

---

Here's a handy table with forms of **lie** and **lay**:

[image]

(from "[Lie Lay Practice Worksheet](http://freeology.com/grammar/lie-lay-practice-worksheet/)", Freeology.com, licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 license)

---

Read also:

- [LIE OR LAY? SOME DISASTROUSLY UNHELPFUL GUIDANCE](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000877.html) - Language Log